# Content Copy prevention & content select prevention Script is also preventing Select working in HTML Form

Tags: html, select, copy-paste

I am using a small script for preventing the copy/paste & select/ drag prevention to protect my content from being easily copied from my web page. It is working very fine in all browsers and preventing all that. But the problem I am facing it with its use - The  select form in the web-page is also not working. I am not able to select the option in that form, it is only visible but not operating. I have one simple select html form for selecting the number of rows a visitor want to see in the page - but this is not working , select options are not opening. I think that script is preventing this html form select too. So please help me in this case, what modification i can do so that my both things keep on working. OR Suggest me some new code for both of these should work.

The script i am using immediate after my BODY tag is form preventing copy and select/drag is given below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
      function disableselect(e) {             
          return false 
      } 
      function reEnable() { 
          return true 
      } 

      document.onselectstart = new Function("return false") 

      if (window.sidebar) { 
          document.onmousedown = disableselect                    // for mozilla           
          document.onclick = reEnable 
      } 

      function clickIE() { 
          if (document.all) { 
              (message); 
              return false; 
          } 
      } 


      document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false") 

      var element = document.getElementById('tbl'); 

      element.onmousedown = function () { return false; }        // For Mozilla Browser

   </script>
```

Please look into this that what changes should I do in the above script so that my  form select also starts working. Or please suggest some other snippet of script which solves both problems. Well I would like to tell here that the above script is not mine, I had taken that from the net as I am not too much high level program. But I know, I must get help here... Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could use css to allow non-select (which would stop from copying too)

Comment: Can you please elaborate it, please give in details with code example if you can - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a different method of copying prevention using css like so:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Then proceed to take out the JS causing your troubles.